# Margin inconsistencies, z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index, margin

I recently just created a website for a company, http://visionaryminds.com/ ,  For the most part everything is good except for a few browser inconsistencies.

The reason I am posting is an inconstancy I noticed between Chrome and Firefox (IE also had this problem but I used conditional statements to fix them not realizing the problem bled into Firefox)

http://www.visionaryminds.com

When you open the page you will notice a section in the dark gray rounded container that says "Welcome!".  **In chrome, it is placed where it should be, creating a nice even margin around the entire container.**  **However in Firefox and IE the margin is triple the size.**

It appears that despite being in it's own container it's being pushed by the header container outside of it.  Anyone have any ideas? I have been at this for days, playing with positioning and z-index with little luck.

Thanks to all who reply,
Spencer

Comment: full time instructor is hot ! Lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of negative margins.

In `.content_container` remove `margin-top: -50px` and use `top: -50px` instead.

Comment: Thanks my head hurts, now mine no longer does!